# Magento coupon discount

Tags: php, magento, coupon

I am setting up magento store which buy stuff from customers. Instead of decreasing Price of the product, I want to increase the price of the product using coupon code. in which file i need to make changes for this.

Update 1:

Thanks Amit. 
I have another question. I like to change "Discount" to "Promotion" in cart and onepage checkout. However, I can't find any file location. I have turn on the Template Path Hints from Configuration. Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: interesting ... and why do u need to do this ??

Comment: For example, if someone is trying to sell his book and he is also using coupon code, he will get $5 more for his book

Comment: I have another question. I like to change "Discount" to "Promotion" in cart and onepage checkout. However, I can't find any file location. I have turn on the Template Path Hints from Configuration. Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only fixed amount discount, then you can remove the validate for Discount Amount field so that you can add negative value in this field, so when you try to apply this coupon it will automatically add that amount instead to decrease. So you need to override below two classes.

For more details on Magento override see [this](http://ka.lpe.sh/2011/06/08/overriderewrite-magento-core-blocks-and-controllers/) Link.

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Actions
```

find this code

```
$fieldset->addField('discount_amount', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'discount_amount',
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'validate-not-negative-number',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Discount Amount'),
        ));
```

and change it to

```
$fieldset->addField('discount_amount', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'discount_amount',
            'required' => true,
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Discount Amount'),
        ));
```

and remove the below code

```
if ($this->hasDiscountAmount()) {
            if ((int)$this->getDiscountAmount() < 0) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('rule')->__('Invalid discount amount.'));
            }
        }
```

from

```
Mage_Rule_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave()
```

Comment: I have another question. I like to change "Discount" to "Promotion" in cart and onepage checkout. However, I can't find any file location. I have turn on the Template Path Hints from Configuration. Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: I have post the solution in your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299009/magneto-coupon-discount

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the CartController.php in Mage/Checkout/Controllers and at the Mage_Sales_Model_Quote model with its methode -collectTotals().

You need to create a new module where you override the model or create an observer.

Comment: I have another question. I like to change "Discount" to "Promotion" in cart and onepage checkout. However, I can't find any file location. I have turn on the Template Path Hints from Configuration. Can anyone help me out ?