# Magento coupon discount translation

Tags: php, magento, discount, coupon

I like to change "Discount" to "Promotion" in cart and onepage checkout. However, I can't find any file location. I have turn on the Template Path Hints from Configuration. Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 4):

I think you'd do that in your translation file here: app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv Just change "Discount Codes","Discount Codes" to "Discount Codes","Promotion Codes" or whatever.

But the coupon phtml is here: app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/cart/coupon.phtml